# Codesign error in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9, codesign

I have the strange error. When my app is compiling, Xcode 9 asks for password in keychain. But when I enter the password, this window appears a lot and so on ad infinitum. If I do not enter the password, then the application will not be compiled.

[image]

Text: Code sign want to sign using key LG in your keychain. 
Button : always allow, deny, allow

Comment: Which language is this ? You should post your screenshot in English so that other people can understand and help you!

Comment: @Lion updated text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter your password and selecting the "Always allow" button should help.